# <IPython.core.display.HTML object> in databricks notebook

Tags: python, databricks, pandas-profiling

while using `to_notebook()` & `to_widgets()` of pandas profiling in databricks notebook output looks like `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>` this.

is there a way i can get the actual output.

I tried with `displayHTML()`, it works only for `to_html()`

for the commands

```
profile = pp.ProfileReport(df, title = "Biosample Repository Data Profiling Report", explorative=True)
profile.to_notebook()
```

The output is

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```